# gvim: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

Tags: gvim, error

I use Cygwin's X-windows.  For Gvim (not Vim) I've gotten warnings
similar to the following for years:

```
** (gvim:432): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address:
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected
from message bus without replying
```

The actual shown number varies as I repeatedly invoke Gvim.

After years, I finally found an work-around that avoids this.  I thought it would help others, so I'm posting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer starting [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg168500.html) and ending [here](https://gist.github.com/jeffcogswell/62395900725acef1c0a5a608f7eb7a05):

```
export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```

The latter linked page refers to this as a hack.  Since it seems to be a Gnome thing, and I don't use Gnome on the system where I get this error, I am willing to accept whatever deep dark problems that it covers up.